# Understanding Expected Running Time of Randomized Algorithms

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, probability-theory, randomized-algorithms, average-case

I want to understand the expected running time and the worse-case expected running time.

I got confused when I saw this figure ([source](http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse326/03au/lectures/19-rand-datastr.pdf)),

[image: source]

where $I$ is the input and $S$ is the sequence of random numbers.

What I don't understand from the above equation is why the expected running time is given for one particular input $I$?

I always thought that for a problem $\pi$,  $E(\pi) = \sum_{input \in Inputs}(Pr(input)*T(input))$ , isn't this correct?

So, let's assume Pr(x) is the uniform distribution, and we are to find the expected running time of the problem of searching an element in a $n$ element array using linear search.

Isn't the expected running time for linear search,

$$E(LinearSearch) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_1^ni $$

And what about the worst case expected running time, isn't it the time complexity of having the worst behavior? Like the figure below,

[image]

I would highly appreciate if someone can help me understand the two figures above.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two notions of expected running time here. Given a randomized algorithm, its running time depends on the random coin tosses. The *expected running time* is the expectation of the running time with respect to the coin tosses. This quantity depends on the input. For example, quicksort with a random pivot has expected running time $\Theta(n\log n)$. This quantity depends on the length of the input $n$.

Given either a randomized or a deterministic algorithm, one can also talk about its expected running time *on a random input* from some fixed distribution. For example, deterministic [quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) (with a fixed pivot) has expected running time $\Theta(n\log n)$ on a randomly distributed input of length $n$. This is known as average-case analysis. Your example of linear search fits this category.

A related concept is *smoothed analysis*, in which we are interested in the expected running time of an algorithm in the *neighborhood* of a particular input. For example, while the [simplex algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm) has exponential running time on some inputs, in the "vicinity" of *each* input it runs in polynomial time *in expectation*.